# How do I selectively copy text from a series of files and paste into one?

Tags: windows, batch-file, concatenation

I have a large number of identically named files in a bunch of separate folders.  For example:
mods\Lady Knight\media\units\items\armor
mods\Paladin\media\units\items\armor
mods\Necromancer\media\units\items\armor

In each one of these folders there would be for example:
a_chest_magic_04a.dat
a_chest_magic_04b.dat
a_chest_magic_04c.dat

These .dat files are really just .txt files with a different extension.  Within each of these files is a bunch of lines of text which are the same amongst the files of the same name in different folders.  So for example the first few lines of these:

mods\Lady Knight\media\units\items\armor\a_chest_magic_04a.dat
mods\Paladin\media\units\items\armor\a_chest_magic_04a.dat
mods\Necromancer\media\units\items\armor\a_chest_magic_04a.dat

would be the exact same, but between

mods\Lady Knight\media\units\items\armor\a_chest_magic_04a.dat
mods\Lady Knight\media\units\items\armor\a_chest_magic_04b.dat

the text would be different.
However, at the end of every file is something like this:

```
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:DESTROYER
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/destroyer/dest_scale_chest.png
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/destroyer/scale_set.mesh
<STRING>ICON:scalevest
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:ALCHEMIST
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/alchemist/alchemist_hvyleather_chest.png
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/alchemist/hvyleather_set.mesh
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:VANQUISHER
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/vanquisher/vanquisher_buckled.mesh
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/vanquisher/buckled_chest.png
<STRING>ICON:vanq_buckled_body
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:LADY KNIGHT
<STRING>TEXTURE:media\wardrobe\ladyknight\buckled_chest.png
<STRING>MESH:media\wardrobe\ladyknight\vanquisher_buckled.mesh
<STRING>ICON:vanq_buckled_body
[/WARDROBE]
[/UNIT]
```

The lines between the last set of [WARDROBE] tags is different in each version of the file.  What I want to do is combine them so that all of these different [WARDROBE] groups are listed at the end so the last part of **a_chest_magic_04a.dat** would look like this:

```
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:DESTROYER
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/destroyer/dest_scale_chest.png
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/destroyer/scale_set.mesh
<STRING>ICON:scalevest
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:ALCHEMIST
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/alchemist/alchemist_hvyleather_chest.png
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/alchemist/hvyleather_set.mesh
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:VANQUISHER
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/vanquisher/vanquisher_buckled.mesh
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/vanquisher/buckled_chest.png
<STRING>ICON:vanq_buckled_body
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:LADY KNIGHT
<STRING>TEXTURE:media\wardrobe\ladyknight\buckled_chest.png
<STRING>MESH:media\wardrobe\ladyknight\vanquisher_buckled.mesh
<STRING>ICON:vanq_buckled_body
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:PALADIN
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/paladin/vanquisher_buckled.mesh
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/paladin/buckled_chest.png
<STRING>ICON:paladin_buckled_body
[/WARDROBE]
[WARDROBE]
<STRING>CLASS:NECROMANCER
<STRING>TEXTURE:media/wardrobe/alchemist/alchemist_hvyleather_chest.png
<STRING>MESH:media/wardrobe/alchemist/hvyleather_set.mesh
[/WARDROBE]
[/UNIT]
```

There are about a dozen folders each containing their own slightly varying copies of the same 150 or so files.  I could copy one of the folders to use as the starting point for the master.  The end goal being master copies (of the 150ish files) which contain the wardrobe sections from each of the different folders' source files.  I'd prefer to do it in Windows because I've had trouble in the past with Windows and Linux carriage returns not being the same.

I had a basic scripting class about a year and a half ago in college but this is quite a bit above that.  I think the logic of the batch file would be something like

1) delete [/UNIT] from the end of every file
2) copy the last wardrobe section from each instance of a file and concatenate that to the end of the master
3) repeat the above for each file in the folder
4) add [/UNIT] to the end of the master files

Can anyone with some boss scripting skills help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is good.

1. for iterating over all of your files, `FOR` is your friend. Read `HELP FOR` and try something simple in the command line

   ```
   for /r %a in (a_chest_*.dat) do @echo %a
   ```

   make sure you get all the files you want
2. to move this code into a BAT file, you need to replace %a to %%a. Also, you want to copy the first file to be used as the seed for all the rest of the files. Try something like this..

   ```
   set first=
   for /r %%a in (a_chest_*.dat) do (
     echo %%a
     if .!first!==. (
       copy %%a wardrobes.txt
       set first=%%a
     ) 
   )
   ```
3. extracting the last WARDROBE section of each file is a bit more tricky

   because you want to extract just the last occurrence of the WARDROBE section, you need to read the file twice, the first time to find the line where the copy should begin, and the second time to actualyy do the extraction.

   `FOR` is your friend, first to find the lines of the last [WARDROBE] and the last [/UNIT]

   ```
   set linenum=0
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (a_chest_magic_04c.dat ) do (
     set /a linenum+=1
     if %%a==[WARDROBE] set fromhere=!linenum!
     if %%a==[/UNIT] set tohere=!linenum!
   )
   ```

   and second, to find that place and extract the lines

   ```
   set linenum=0
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (a_chest_magic_04c.dat ) do (
    set /a linenum+=1
    if !linenum! geq !fromhere! (
      if !linenum! lss !tohere! (
       echo %%a
      )
    )
   )
   goto :eof
   ```
4. putting the pieces we got so far together

   ```
   @echo off
   setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   set first=
   for /r %%a in (*.dat) do (
     if .!first!==. (
       copy %%a wardrobes.txt
       set first=%%a
     ) else (
       (
         call :extractlastwardrobe %%a
       ) >>wardrobes.txt
     )
   )
   goto :eof

   :extractlastwardrobe
   set linenum=0
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
     set /a linenum+=1
     if %%a==[WARDROBE] set fromhere=!linenum!
     if %%a==[/UNIT] set tohere=!linenum!
   )
   set linenum=0
   for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
     set /a linenum+=1
     if !linenum! geq !fromhere! (
       if !linenum! lss !tohere! (
         echo %%a
       )
     )
   )
   goto :eof
   ```

and you are **almost** done. You still need to remove the [/UNIT] line from the seed file and add it at the end of the result file. I leave this as an exercise.